# MongoDB / Mongoose: Return value of aggregation (sum)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I hope someone can help me: I want to write a little code with javascript and mongoose. My goal is: People can sign in for an event by using an online-formula.
They have to specify last name, amount of people (per group), email, time (slot).
I want to write a control structure that checks if there is already a specific number of people in one slot (for example max. 50 people in slot 11 clock).
I don't know how to return a single value out of the aggregation.

My code:

```
const notesSchema = {
    lastname: String,
    people: Number,
    email: String,
    time: Number
}

const Note = mongoose.model("Note", notesSchema)

async function totalamount(){
    Note.aggregate(
        [{
        $group:
        {
            _id: null,
        total: { $sum: "$people"}
        }}
            ])
     

}
```

Can someone help me, please?
Sorry for by bad english.

Best regards from Germany
Dave

Comment: Please start by [mongoose docs about using aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-aggregate). Pay attention to the `await` keyword usage. Once you get the result. You can use `res[0].total`

Answer (score 1):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/x8H83d4RO9x

Input:

```
[
  {
    lastname: "Beckenbauer",
    people: 11,
    email: "franz@beckenbauer.de",
    time: 1
  },
  {
    lastname: "Funkel",
    people: 22,
    email: "friedhelm@funkel.de",
    time: 2
  },
  {
    lastname: "Löw",
    people: 25,
    email: "joachim@löw.de",
    time: 1
  },
  {
    lastname: "Matthäus",
    people: 30,
    email: "lothar@matthäus.de",
    time: 2
  },
  {
    lastname: "Karl-Heinz Rummenigge",
    people: 38,
    email: "karl-heinz@rummenigge.de",
    time: 3
  }
]
```

Agg:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$bucket": {
      "groupBy": "$time",
      "boundaries": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "default": "literal",
      "output": {
        "total": {
          "$sum": "$people"
        },
        "lastname": {
          $push: "$lastname"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "lastname": [
      "Beckenbauer",
      "Löw"
    ],
    "total": 36
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "lastname": [
      "Funkel",
      "Matthäus"
    ],
    "total": 52
  },
  {
    "_id": "literal",
    "lastname": [
      "Karl-Heinz Rummenigge"
    ],
    "total": 38
  }
]
```

It's assumed that you have only 3 slots. If you need more, extend `boundaries`. Also, in order to simplify it slots are represented as indices (we can easily switch to Date if it's needed)

Your English is still better then my German ;)